# for-loop doesn't give the expected results

Tags: python, numpy

I have a pretty simple for loop which doesn't give the expected results. It runs through a ndarray column row-by-row and should categorize e.g. the statements ' Heavy Vehicle' or ' Car' to numeric values (I know they are also strings).

```
for k in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    if data[k, 1] == ' Car' or ' Motorcycle' or ' Bicycle' or ' Pedestrian':
        data[k, 1] = '1'
    elif data[k, 1] == ' Heavy Vehicle' or ' Medium Vehicle' or ' Bus':
        data[k, 1] = '2'
    else:
        data[k, 1] = '3'
```

However the result is that python sets all values to '1' even those cells with the statement ' Heavy Vehicle'. I don't know why python doesn't replace the values with the defined numeric values.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you'll have to repeat the variable you compare to, e.g. `if data[k, 1] == ' Car' or data[k, 1] == ' Motorcycle'` etc. - you might simplify e.g. by using [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Comment: Ah yes I've got my mistake. Thanks a lot @MrFuppes!

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence, the `==` is evaluated first, and then the `or`s.  So `data` is tested only against 'Car'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### String are also boolean objects in Python!

You are basically doing `False Or True`, so `True` for each cycle.

Try this:

```
print(Bool(""))           # Empty String is False
print(Bool("String"))     # Full String is True
```

You should check string again, like:

```
for k in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    if data[k, 1] == ' Car' or data[k, 1] == ' Motorcycle' or data[k, 1] == ' Bicycle' or data[k, 1] == ' Pedestrian':
        data[k, 1] = '1'
    elif data[k, 1] == ' Heavy Vehicle' or data[k, 1] == ' Medium Vehicle' or data[k, 1] == ' Bus':
        data[k, 1] = '2'
    else:
        data[k, 1] = '3'
```

But I will personally write something like this:

```
moving_objects = [['Car','Motorcycle','Bicycle','Pedestrian'], 
                  ['Heavy Vehicle','Medium Vehicle','Bus']]

for k in range(0, data.shape[0]:
    data[k, 1] = [i if k in moving_objects[i][0] else 3 for i, m  in enumerate(moving_objects) ][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = np.array([[None]*3]*3)
data[:,1] = [' Car', ' Heavy Vehicle', 'CCC']
print(data)

for k in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    if any(x == data[k, 1] for x in [' Car', ' Motorcycle' , ' Bicycle' , ' Pedestrian']):
        data[k, 1] = '1'
    elif any(x == data[k, 1] for x in [' Heavy Vehicle', ' Medium Vehicle',' Bus']):
        data[k, 1] = '2'
    else:
        data[k, 1] = '3'
        
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[None ' Car' None]
 [None ' Heavy Vehicle' None]
 [None 'CCC' None]]

[[None '1' None]
 [None '2' None]
 [None '3' None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The programm actually works as expected: the following statement `... or 'Motorcycle` will always returns `True` because what you're doing is asking `if 'Motorcycle':` and if you do `bool('Motorcycle)` it will return `True`.

Therefore I suggest you refactor your code like shown below:

```py
for k in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    _ = data[k, 1]
    if _ in [' Car', ' Motorcycle', ' Bicycle', ' Pedestrian']:
        data[k, 1] = '1'
    elif _ in [' Heavy Vehicle', ' Medium Vehicle', ' Bus']:
        data[k, 1] = '2'
    else:
        data[k, 1] = '3'
```